# Is there a better mplayer command line interface, or another good CLI music player?

Tags: linux, command-line, music, mplayer

I generally prefer to do things on the command line when I can. Mplayer is a great tool for playing all sorts of media, but the command line interface sucks. Some things I'd like to see in a CLI media player would include:

- Clean output - easy to understand, not cluttered by a bunch of stuff that's irrelevant in day-to-day use
- ID3 information
- Progress bar & play time info (total time, current time, time left)
- Play queue - list of songs with lengths and an indication of where you are currently

Comment: There is one listed on the mplayer site, called "mplay", but I was unable to make it work. There is no debian file, nor is it in the ubuntu repositories, and the install file barfs when I try to run it. So I don't really consider that a valid option at this point. If someone recommends it (and has an idea how to make it work), I'd consider it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've settled on using `mpd` (Music Player Daemon), with a CLI interface called `ncmpcpp`. This combination works quite well, and there are some excellent companion apps to do things like audioscrobbling (`mpdscribble`), and controlling it with media buttons (`indimpc`). It's perhaps not as light-weight a solution as `mplayer`, but it feels like a good balance.

Another CLI media player that's worthy of note, although I use it less often, is `herrie`. It's got all of the features I outlined in the original question, and it's very lightweight.

Comment: 1+ `mpd` + `ncmpcpp` is simple and clean. Managing playlists and queuing songs are very easy once you get the keyboard shortcuts right.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [`cmus`](http://cmus.sourceforge.net/)

From the [Wikipedia article:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmus)

> cmus (C* Music Player) is a small and fast console audio player for Unix-like operating systems. cmus is distributed under the terms of the GNU General Public License (GPL) and operates exclusively through a text-only interface, built with ncurses.

I use it for listening random songs from my library. For most purposes though, `mplayer` is just fine for me. E.g. options like `-playlist`, `-shuffle` help. You can also fine-grain the amount and colorize the output of `mplayer` if you find it too much/less.

Comment: Can you get it to play the audio of, e.g., `.flv` files? Those are the ones I most often get with youtube-dl, and in mplayer[2], it's possible to just play them in a tty (obviously, with no video).

Comment: I doubt that `cmus` is able to do it. But better than flv downloads from **youtube** is this: 1. switch youtube to [html5](http://youtube.com/html5). 2. on playing a clip click: **website icon** -> **More information** -> **Media** -> In the column type there is one *video*. 3. select this row & save as `clip.webm`. 4. Run `ffmpeg -i clip.webm -vn -acodec copy out.ogg`

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure it'll help, have you checked out the vlc command line? I haven't used it, but I VLC when it comes to quality playback, and it should do most of the things that you would use mplayer for (if not all of them).

http://www.videolan.org/doc/vlc-user-guide/en/ch04.html

Comment: Yeah, VLC command line doesn't really do what I'm looking for. It will play things, but it's not the type of user-friendly CLI interface I'd like to play music with on a daily basis.

Answer (score 0):

MPS - bash based front end for mplayer in slave mode.

git clone https://github.com/sshpass/mps